# paper trails objecat_changes to show in readable form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paper-trail-gem

i am using paper trails i am showing changes on update through object_changes.
my view code is as below

```
 <% @users.each do |u|%>
    <% u.versions.each do |v| %>
    <tr id="" data-hook="admin_products_index_rows" class="odd">
    <td class=""><%=v.object_changes%></td> </tr>
```

my output is not readbale formate it is like this

```
    --- first_name: - john - desil updated_at: - 2015-06-23 06:56:49.211694000 Z - 2015-07-10 12:03:44.224713593 Z
```

i can remove updated_at but ---first_name is also user friendly formate.
is there any way show these changes in user friendly formate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
results = u.versions.collect(&:changeset)
```

This will return you hash with the key having table attribute and value will have a hash in which first one showing previous value and second showing updated one. and you can traverse it

Answer (score 0):

i am able to solve this by loop over hash my code

```
<% @products.each do |p|%>
<% p.versions.each do |v| %>
<tr>
     <td class="">
      <table>
    <%v.changeset.each do |k,v|%>
    <tr><td><%=k%></td><td><%=v[0]+" to "+v[1]%></td></tr>
    <%end%>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<%end%>
 <%end%>
```

my output snap short is attached
[image]